# QTableWidget cell widgets dissapear after swap

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtablewidget

I have QTableWidget with 3 columns. First column contains QTableWidgetItem with row name, two other columns contains two cell widgets.

[image]

I tried to swap table rows with the following code:

```
connect(upButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this, protectionWidget]()
    {
        int index = m_protectionWidgets->indexOf(protectionWidget);
        int upperIndex = index - 1;
        if (upperIndex >= 0)
        {
            QTableWidgetItem *nameItem = m_protectionsTable->takeItem(index, 0);
            ProtectionWidget *protectionWidgetCopy = protectionWidget;
            QWidget *buttons = m_protectionsTable->cellWidget(index, 2);

            QTableWidgetItem *upperNameItem = m_protectionsTable->takeItem(upperIndex, 0);
            ProtectionWidget *upperProtectionWidget = m_protectionWidgets->at(upperIndex);
            QWidget *upperButtons = m_protectionsTable->cellWidget(upperIndex, 2);

            m_protectionsTable->setItem(upperIndex, 0, nameItem);
            m_protectionsTable->setCellWidget(upperIndex, 1, protectionWidgetCopy);
            m_protectionsTable->setCellWidget(upperIndex, 2, buttons);

            m_protectionsTable->setItem(index, 0, upperNameItem);
            m_protectionsTable->setCellWidget(index, 1, upperProtectionWidget);
            m_protectionsTable->setCellWidget(index, 2, upperButtons);

            m_protectionWidgets->removeAt(index);
            m_protectionWidgets->insert(upperIndex, 1, protectionWidget);
        }
    });
```

But when I click upButton cellWidgets disappear.

[image]

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening to you, documented for [`setCellWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget) is that you cannot set a widget on a cell without deleting the widget already present. It is a rather tricky thing to detect with debugging tools because the deletion is done on the next execution of the event loop thanks to a call to `QObject::deleteLater`, long after your lambda has already finished executing.

There is no way around the deletion taking place, however there are ways to make the deletion harmless. I see 2 ways:

1. Place your `protectionWidget` and `buttons` inside sacrifical widgets. by resetting their parents at the right time, you can achieve an effect where only empty sacrifical widgets get deleted during the next calls to `setCellWidget`.
2. Same as the above but you stop calling `setCellWidget` completely and instead just swaps the parent of the widgets.

The below code demonstrates your mistake (A & B), the first method (C & D) and the 2nd method (E & F). Note that you need to consider whether to keep the lambdas `createWidget`, `extractButton` and/or `swapParent` as is or turn them into protected/private methods.

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QTableWidget t;
    t.setRowCount(6);
    t.setColumnCount(2);

    t.setItem(0, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Original: A"));
    t.setItem(1, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Original: B"));
    t.setItem(2, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Method 1: C"));
    t.setItem(3, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Method 1: D"));
    t.setItem(4, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Method 2: E"));
    t.setItem(5, 0, new QTableWidgetItem("Method 2: F"));

    auto createWidget = [](QPushButton* button) -> QWidget*
    {
        QWidget* result = new QWidget();
        QLayout* l = new QVBoxLayout(result);
        l->setContentsMargins(QMargins());
        l->addWidget(button);
        button->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
        return result;
    };
    auto extractButton = [] (QWidget* widget) -> QPushButton*
    {
        QPushButton* result = widget->findChild<QPushButton*>();
        result->setParent(nullptr);
        return result;
    };
    auto swapParent = [](QWidget* from, QWidget* to) -> void
    {
        auto fromChild = from->findChild<QWidget*>(), toChild = to->findChild<QWidget*>();
        from->layout()->removeWidget(fromChild);
        to->layout()->removeWidget(toChild);
        fromChild->setParent(to);
        toChild->setParent(from);
        from->layout()->addWidget(toChild);
        to->layout()->addWidget(fromChild);
    };

    auto bA = new QPushButton("A"), bB = new QPushButton("B"),
         bC = new QPushButton("C"), bD = new QPushButton("D"),
         bE = new QPushButton("E"), bF = new QPushButton("F");
    QObject::connect(bA, &QObject::destroyed, []() { qDebug() << "Button A destroyed "; });
    QObject::connect(bB, &QObject::destroyed, []() { qDebug() << "Button B destroyed "; });
    QObject::connect(bC, &QObject::destroyed, []() { qDebug() << "Button C destroyed "; });
    QObject::connect(bD, &QObject::destroyed, []() { qDebug() << "Button D destroyed "; });
    QObject::connect(bE, &QObject::destroyed, []() { qDebug() << "Button E destroyed "; });
    QObject::connect(bF, &QObject::destroyed, []() { qDebug() << "Button F destroyed "; });

    t.setCellWidget(0, 1, bA);
    t.setCellWidget(1, 1, bB);
    t.setCellWidget(2, 1, createWidget(bC));
    t.setCellWidget(3, 1, createWidget(bD));
    t.setCellWidget(4, 1, createWidget(bE));
    t.setCellWidget(5, 1, createWidget(bF));
    //End of the initialization.
    //The next lines simulate the lambdas connected to the button signals with:
    // - what not do to: swap A<->B, unprotected
    // - method 1: swap C<->D, each protected by a sacrifical widget
    // - method 2: reparent E and F instead of literally swapping them
    auto b0 = t.cellWidget(0, 1), b1 = t.cellWidget(1, 1),
         b2 = t.cellWidget(2, 1), b3 = t.cellWidget(3, 1),
         b4 = t.cellWidget(4, 1), b5 = t.cellWidget(5, 1);
    //b0 == bA && b1 == bB && b2 == bC && b3 == bD && b4 == bE && b5 == bF

    //Incorrect for A and B (see the qDebug messages)
    t.setCellWidget(0, 1, b1);
    t.setCellWidget(1, 1, b0);

    //Method 1
    t.setCellWidget(2, 1, createWidget(extractButton(b3)));
    t.setCellWidget(3, 1, createWidget(extractButton(b2)));
    //Method 2
    swapParent(b4, b5);

    // The next 2 lines are only to exit cleanly.
    t.setCellWidget(0, 1, nullptr);
    t.setCellWidget(1, 1, nullptr);

    t.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

It should go without saying but this demonstration seriously need a lot of pointer checks.